# Открытие popup окна при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать открытие popup окна при загрузке страницы? Стандартные методы типа 
`window.open` не работают, т.к. браузер блокирует их.

Answer (score 1):

Всплывающие окна в браузере открываются через `window.open`. Обойти защиту может быть и получиться, но не нужно - это не правильно. Защита на то и создана, чтобы всякая фигня не "всплывала".

Поэтому лучше обходиться "внутренними" окнами - внутри документа. Это конечно не окно, но можно добиться желаемого результата - человеку сразу видно, что-то выскачило поверх содержимого сайта.

Можно воспользоваться разными плагинами к библиотеке `jQuery`. К примеру `fancyApps`

Comment: в моем случае не катит, так как у меня сервис сокращения ссылок, пользователь фактически не видит страницы - только она загружается, как он отправляется туда, куда ведет сокращенная ссылка, потому он на ней не остается, никакие другие методы не подходят, только принудительное открывание нужной мне страницы (ссылки) в новом окне.